# VBA - What Sheet does 'WorksheetFunction' Reference?

Tags: excel, vba

I know WorksheetFunction is used as a container for Microsoft Excel worksheet functions but don't know how to use the function in reference of a specific sheet.

I want to use the 'WorksheetFunction.CountA' function on a specific sheet but don't know how to reference that sheet.

Something like:

> ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("somesheet").WorksheetFunction.CountA

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet2")`? Edit: per edit to OP `Sheets("somesheet")`. You qualify it right before XD Edit2: am I getting trolled XD Edit3: is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: What determine the sheet is the ranges in the formula not the function itself.

Comment: Ah my fault. Yea, what Scott said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a sheet but a container for all the functions one would use ona sheet but allows them to be used in VBA.

It is accesible from Application object.

e.g.

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange)
```

or from reference page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841212.aspx

```
Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C10") 
answer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(myRange) 
MsgBox answer
```

Comment: So what range are we checking here? Range for Sheet1, Sheet2, SheetN ect..?

Comment: @BDillan See my comment above.  You declare the sheet with the ranges in the formula.  In this example when setting `myRange` you would declare a sheet on which that range resides.  Then vba uses that sheet on which that range resides.  You declare it when you set the ranges in the formula.